# Beaglebone Black and Qt5.10

Tags: c, linux, qt, ubuntu, beagleboneblack

I am using Beaglebone Black Rev C with BB-View CapeManager as follow:

1. Latest kernel version: "Linux arm 4.15.0-bone2.1 #1 Tue Jan 30 11:48:09 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux"
2. BBB fire up correctly and screen work correctly
3. Build Qt-everywhere package 5.11 fro io.qtdownload site
4. The Qt for ARM build successfully and deployed across Beaglbone black
5. A small test program developed on x86_64bit development Machine, targeted for an ARM.
6. I am using cross-compiler toolchain "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-7.2.1-*"
7. Binary program definitely generating executable for an ARM cpu
8. After deployment of the binary test program on BBB machine.

I get the following error:

> Traceback: "./test: /**lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6**: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/local/qt5.11/lib/libQt5Core.so.5)"

9. I ran on BBB "sudo ldconfig -v

   9.a The lib 'ib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6' exists in the given path

   9.b After executing command objdump -p test following result I get...

...the following:

```
test:     file format elf32-littlearm
Program Header:
0x70000001 off    0x00000a58 vaddr 0x00010a58 paddr 0x00010a58 align 2**2
         filesz 0x00000018 memsz 0x00000018 flags r--
    PHDR off    0x00000034 vaddr 0x00010034 paddr 0x00010034 align 2**2
         filesz 0x00000120 memsz 0x00000120 flags r-x
  INTERP off    0x00000154 vaddr 0x00010154 paddr 0x00010154 align 2**0
         filesz 0x00000019 memsz 0x00000019 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00010000 paddr 0x00010000 align 2**16
         filesz 0x00000a74 memsz 0x00000a74 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x00000ec4 vaddr 0x00020ec4 paddr 0x00020ec4 align 2**16
         filesz 0x0000018c memsz 0x00000194 flags rw-
 DYNAMIC off    0x00000ed0 vaddr 0x00020ed0 paddr 0x00020ed0 align 2**2
         filesz 0x00000130 memsz 0x00000130 flags rw-
    NOTE off    0x00000170 vaddr 0x00010170 paddr 0x00010170 align 2**2
         filesz 0x00000044 memsz 0x00000044 flags r--
   STACK off    0x00000000 vaddr 0x00000000 paddr 0x00000000 align 2**4
         filesz 0x00000000 memsz 0x00000000 flags rw-
   RELRO off    0x00000ec4 vaddr 0x00020ec4 paddr 0x00020ec4 align 2**0
         filesz 0x0000013c memsz 0x0000013c flags r--

Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libQt5Gui.so.5
  NEEDED               libQt5Core.so.5
  NEEDED               librt.so.1
  NEEDED               libdl.so.2
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  RPATH                /usr/local/qt5.11/lib
  INIT                 0x000107e0
  FINI                 0x00010a28
  INIT_ARRAY           0x00020ec4
  INIT_ARRAYSZ         0x00000008
  FINI_ARRAY           0x00020ecc
  FINI_ARRAYSZ         0x00000004
  HASH                 0x000101b4
  STRTAB               0x00010408
  SYMTAB               0x000102a8
  STRSZ                0x000002a2
  SYMENT               0x00000010
  DEBUG                0x00000000
  PLTGOT               0x00021000
  PLTRELSZ             0x00000060
  PLTREL               0x00000011
  JMPREL               0x00010780
  REL                  0x00010768
  RELSZ                0x00000018
  RELENT               0x00000008
  VERNEED              0x000106d8
  VERNEEDNUM           0x00000003
  VERSYM               0x000106aa
Version References:
  required from libQt5Core.so.5:
    0x00058a25 0x00 04 Qt_5
  required from libstdc++.so.6:
    0x0849afa3 0x00 07 CXXABI_ARM_1.3.3
    0x02297f89 0x00 06 GLIBCXX_3.4.9
    0x056bafd3 0x00 05 CXXABI_1.3
    0x08922974 0x00 03 GLIBCXX_3.4
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x0d696914 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.4
private flags = 5000400: [Version5 EABI] [hard-float ABI]
```

Please can anyone shed a light on this issue? Cannot figure next to explore?

On Beaglebone Black I am using `rootfs` UBUNTU 16.04...

...and get:

```
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

In addition, I only have a barebone Kernel + rootfs on BB Black board.

Your help, advise tip(s) or any info in this problem will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you,